# Lost any badges and Q&A count after "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" when I tried to change SO's Edit Email Settings

Tags: support, bug, login, email, accounts

Please help me!

Yesterday I tried to change email address in my Stack Overflow account's *Edit profile and settings* → *Edit email settings*.
When I changed previous email to another and clicked on the <kbd>Save</kbd> button then I was redirected to the *confirm.error* page:

[image]

After, when I try to redirect manually to the Stack Overflow site to my profile then I immediately noticed that:

1. the preference *Stack Overflow's theme* has skipped from dark to light.
2. all my badges and subscribe tags have disappeared.
3. on the page [https://stackexchange.com/users/{userid}/{displayname}?tab=accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/%7Buserid%7D/%7Bdisplayname%7D?tab=accounts)
   counters of questions and answers skipped to 0 and 0 respectively:
   [image]

After a while, approximately within the next four hours, except one ([Сonstituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent)), all badges and all subscribe tags were restored. And that's all. The second  and third point from the above remains the same.

Also, I did *Edit Email Settings* while logged (via @outlook.com) into my account (user id) as 5309660 (member for 4 years, 7 month). After an error occurs I received an account number as 5113963 (member for 5 years, 1 month).

Please explain to me: What happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like an account merge was done. I hope between two accounts you actually own ...

Comment: @rene as I remember, 5 years ago, I logged in under google id. After, 4 years ago, I logged in with Outlook.com's mail. As i understood, merge really happened, but with the errors indicated in the question.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a caching problem.

Comment: What do you want fixed? Account merges can't be undone. And the rough UX is unfortunate but I don't see anything that is actually broken (except that it breaks the expectation of least astonishment). And as Robert said: once all caches cleared / purged things normalized for your account, right?

Comment: Not sure I understand why the Constituent badge went missing.

Comment: In fact, yes, I agree with you all (Robert and rene) about caching problem. I'm upset that the page has broken, where displayed all communities with questions/answers counters. I will wait, maybe these are temporary problems with the cache.

Comment: @Scratte me too. [Caucus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1973/caucus) badge has been returned, but [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent) is not.

Comment: @timnavigate shouldiblamecaching.com. Wait an hour, and if it's not back then I guess there's a bigger problem at hand that only devs can shed light on. My guess is that since Constituent is awarded when you actually vote, the system didn't return it because there is no active election. But it may not be wrong.

Comment: Has the situation been resolved?

Comment: @Mast currently (after 24 hours) question and answer counters on Stack Exchange page are still displayed as 0 and 0 respectively, and also [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent) is not returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days of waiting for the cache to update, I just decided to leave an answer to one of the questions posted on Stack Overflow.

After that I went to the Stack Exchange page where published list of account's community with counters of reputation, badges, questions and answers. And it worked, helped fix the problem - all my counters have returned and are displayed correctly:
[image]

*Note: but [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent) badge still not returned.*